# Need to figure out logic with video autoplay. HTML, JS, video.js, PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, video, video.js

tl;dr you can read the question summary at the end.

I need an autoplay with sound on my site, after user agreement on that.
Here is [example](https://video.corriere.it/cronaca/tensione-mondragone-italiani-comunita-bulgara-sedie-balconi-auto-distrutte/0e1955f6-b716-11ea-877f-fd70c3a48db9) (sorry, site is in Italian) of where it is implemented on scroll, which agrees with cookie and video autoplay policy, but I would like to get an agreement on click(user clicks agree button).
The point is to ask user for an agreement on the first visit and then autoplay video without asking for confirmation.
In the above example it is working alomost as I need it to work, but I can't figure out how they did it, please help me to understand this logic.

I know about Google's Policy on media autoplay, so I need user to agree before autoplaying the videos, the same as in the above example.

I have this code:

```
<video id="video" preload="auto" playsinline controls>
    <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

and this code in JS (using video.js and jQuery):

```
var videoPlayer = videojs('video');
videoPlayer.ready(function() {
    var promise = videoPlayer.play();
});
```

Summary:
The main goal is to figure out how does autoplay with sound works(how to implement it) on the example [example](https://video.corriere.it/cronaca/tensione-mondragone-italiani-comunita-bulgara-sedie-balconi-auto-distrutte/0e1955f6-b716-11ea-877f-fd70c3a48db9) (sorry, site is in Italian). It works this way: When user comes on the site first time he gets a notification where user is told that site is using cookies and then if user scrolls or clicks on the site, then autoplay with sound works on current session and on all later sessions on this domain. I need your help in figuring out how this logic can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert the source tag into the video tag after the user clicked onto the agreement button. The html won't be loaded before, so you don't have any Google content on your site.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#enableGoogleContentButton").on("click", function(){
       $("#video").append('<source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">')
    });
});
```

```
<video id="video" preload="auto" playsinline controls>
   
   <!--empty-->
</video>


...

<button id="enableGoogleContentButton"> enable Google Content </button>
```

The example would work with Vanilla JS as well
(I'm not sure if I understood your question, so sorry if I didn't)

### edit

You could store the information about the past click in a cookie/localstorage

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(localstorage.cookieaccept=""){
//if there's no cookie set yet
    $("#enableGoogleContentButton").on("click", function(){
//test for click
       $("#video").append('<source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">');
//set the local storage "cookieaccept" to true
localstorage.cookieaccept="true";
$("#enableGoogleContentButton").remove()
//remove the "enable content"-button
    });
$("document").on("scroll", function(){
//or scroll
       $("#video").append('<source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">');
//set the local storage "cookieaccept" to true
localstorage.cookieaccept="true";
$("#enableGoogleContentButton").remove()
//remove the "enable content"-button

    });
}
else{
//if cookie is already set, add the video
$("#video").append('<source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">')
    $("#enableGoogleContentButton").remove()
//remove the "enable content"-button

}
});
```

I hope this will meet your expactations

Comment: Thank you! No, I dont think this is what I need, it seems this code will be asking user every time if he agrees.
But I need some kind of logic that will be autoplaying video every time user comes to my domain, after user agrees with an agreement just once. Take a look at the example I linked.
Also added summary of the question, Would appreciate if you read that and maybe find a soultion.

Comment: Thanks for an update. This code doesn't seem to help with autoplay afterwards, I will try to check it once more later.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think it’s possible. The site must pass the MEI first.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#mei

Comment: thanks for an answer. Did you check the example, which I liked in question? They made it somehow, maybe you can figure out how they did it.
It autoplays with sound after user confirmed their policy (by scrolling usually or by clicking) and user needs to confirm just once.
But I can't make it to work the same way.
I was able to run video when user clicks on my site, but it requires clicking every time there is a video, but on the example site user need click once or even scroll one to accept their policy and the they autoplay videos with sound.